# Unmount MTP device via command line

Tags: usb, unmounting, mtp

My MTP device auto mounts on the desktop every time I boot or re connect the camera via usb.
The problem is my code to copy files does not work unless the MTP device is first unmounted from the desktop.

How can I do this from the command line?
I can retrieve both BUS and Device #'s.

Answer (score 1):

I was asking the wrong question.

Instead of  figuring out how to unmount the device, I needed to find out what process or daemon was claiming it.

I issued

```
ps aux | grep mtp
```

which gave me a few mtp related processes and compared with the camera mounted and unmounted to get the specific process

and then

```
pkill -9 gvfsd-mtp
```

does the trick.